# RxJs Observables nested subscriptions with takeUntil

Tags: rxjs

How am I supposed to get rid of these nested subscriptions? I thought to do that using concatMap or mergeMap - if you agree, how to I handle the takeUntil for inner subscriptions being different than the outer one? I am quite new to operators and RxJs.

```
this.myService.selectedCustomerId
.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
).subscribe((customerId: number) => {
    // Do some stuff...

    this.anotherService.hasPermission("ROLE1", customerId).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.cancel),
    ).subscribe(hasPermission => this.hasPermissionForRole1 = hasPermission);

    this.anotherService.hasPermission("ROLE2", customerId).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.cancel),
    ).subscribe(hasPermission => this.hasPermissionForRole2 = hasPermission);

    this.anotherService.hasPermission("ROLE3", customerId).pipe(
        takeUntil(this.cancel),
    ).subscribe(hasPermission => this.hasPermissionForRole3 = hasPermission);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve it this way:

```
this.myService.selectedCustomerId
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe),
        mergeMap(customerId: number) => {
            const roles = ["ROLE1", "ROLE2", "ROLE3"];
            return forkJoin(
                roles.map(role => this.anotherService.hasPermission(role, customerId))
            )
        }
    ).subscribe(([role1, role2, role3]) => {
        // Do some stuff...
        
    }
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, what you mean is that by using forkJoin there is no need for the takeUntil(this.cancel) part?

Comment: there is no need for takeUntil thanks to the mergeMap operator which automatically subscribe to the inner observable, flattens the resulting observable and automatically unsubscribe from the inner observable. as for the forkJoin operator, it basically groups multiple observables. 
please accept this answer if answers your question so others can benefit from it.